# How to assign a name to a number variable in batch-file

Tags: batch-file

I have code for a number generator, that randomly selects numbers between 1 and 30. I want to use a batch file to make the dinner selections for each week so I don't have to do it myself. My problem is that I don't know how to assign the dinner names to the numbers, then i want it to check if the dinners meet a 'dinner rating', this makes sure that the dinner is healthy enough, if it doesn't meet the rating then the code will/should make it re-pick the dinners.
This is the number generator: (don't tell me that i could do it a better way, I'm sort of a noob)

```
@echo off
echo.
echo             Welcome %username%
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
echo        This Is The Dinner Selector.
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
echo This Program Will Select The Weekly Dinner.
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
set /a selection1=%random% %%30 +1
set /a selection2=%random% %%30 +1
set /a selection3=%random% %%30 +1
set /a selection4=%random% %%30 +1
set /a selection5=%random% %%30 +1
echo %selection1%
echo %selection2%
echo %selection3%
echo %selection4%
echo %selection5%
```

Please help me find a solution to my problem, i am bored of picking healthy dinners by my self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, not entirely sure what you want, but this may be it:

### Main.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion
echo.
echo             Welcome %username%
sleep 2
echo        This Is The Dinner Selector.
sleep 2
echo This Program Will Select The Weekly Dinner.
sleep 2
Echo.
Echo.
Echo How healthy do you want your food [0 - Anything :: 9 - max]
choice /c "1234567890" /n /m ": " /d 0 /t 20
set rate=%errorlevel%
set /a count=0
set /a total=0
for /f %%a in (Dinner.txt) do (set /a total+=1)


:: START LOOP ----------------------
:choose
set /a count+=1
:random
set /a process=0
set sel=
set /a sel=%random% %% %total% + 1

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in (Dinner.txt) do (
    set /a process+=1
    if !process! EQU !sel! (
        if %%b GEQ !rate! (
            set sel=%%a
            )
        )
    )

if "%sel%" EQU "" (Echo %sel%
) Else (
goto :random)

if count leq 5 goto choose
:: END LOOP   ----------------------

cls
Echo Enjoy your meal!
sleep 3
Exit
```

Note this can result in repetitions and/or infinite/really-long loops if the health condition is high.

### Dinner.txt

This is a list of all your choices. it can be as long/short as you want as the batch file adapts to its size.

In there are a total of 5 choices

```
; This is how you format the dinner file: [Food]:[Healthyness 0 - 9]
; Lines starting with semi-colons are ignored (if you want a blank line comment it)
; Examples:
;
; Vegetarian
Salad:9
Pasta:8
;
;
; Non-Veg
Uncooked Meat:2
Pizza:5
Burger:6
Pure Oil:0
```

i'm yet to test this, and can also guarantee there will be an error since it is quite mundane and long, but i'm sure a bit of error-testing will do the job

Mona.

Comment: can i just put any meals i want and give it a rating such as `Pasta:6` then the batch file will adapt, is that what your saying?

Comment: when it asks me how healthy i want it, i put in 5 (for example) then it just waits. You try to run the program on your computer and see if it does it to yours because im bummed

Comment: Give me a few hours and I'll see whats the problem.

Comment: Also, the batch file will adapt not to what ratings you give it, but on how many food items you have in the list, not necesarily 30.

Answer (score 0):

The way to manage several elements of same type, each one identified by an index, is via an [array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure). I strongly suggest you to learn about this topic, and also about Delayed Expansion of environment variables, before you try to use [arrays in Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990). Once you get the basics, you may do something like this:

```
set dinner[1]=Name of first dinner
set dinner[2]=Name of second dinner
set dinner[3]=Name of third dinner, etc
```

Or, in a more advanced way:

```
set i=0
for %%a in (Pasta:9 Dessert:5 Soup:8) do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%b in ("%%a") do (
      set /A i+=1
      set dinner[!i!]=%%b
      set rating[!i!]=%%c
   )
)
```

For example:

```
set /A selection=%random% %% 30 + 1
if !rating[%selection%]! gtr 7 echo Rating of !dinner[%selection%]! correct: greater than 7
```